# How to auto increment a number in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner in jQuery. The following code returns the value of '*number*' when the page loads. I want to auto increment the number ever 2 seconds and update the value and should be available in the page. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one').myNumber({
        number: 12555456
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery is plain javascript. So you simply use a js timer to increment and update the visualization of the value. You might also want to raise a change event on the element and attach a separate onchange handler if you prefer that.

Comment: I'm a beginner and trying to learn things from you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(function(){    
    setInterval(function(){ //Calls a function every X ms as specified in param 2
        var _nbr = parseInt(jQuery('.one').text());//Get number from element as int
        jQuery('.one').text(++_nbr);//Increment variable and puts it in the element
    },2000);//Number of ms between function calls
});
```

Look up those:
[.parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
[.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)
[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)